# Error: Could not find or load main class when class extends HttpServlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, intellij-idea

I have this class:

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hey");
    }
}
```

it works fine. But if I make it extend `HttpServlet`:

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hey");
    }
}
```

I get a `Error: Could not find or load main class Test` error.

I also use Maven, but in this case try to compile&run the class by hand in Idea Intellij.

Edit: I import servlet like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I also tried to test other dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```
public class TestServlet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        Jsoup soup;
    }


}
```

works fine. The moment I add `extends HttpServlet`, I get the error again.

Comment: You get that with what command line?

Comment: @user207421 I get it by right clicking a .java file name in Idea Intellij and clicking Run.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Servlets API file to your Classpath. I wonder you didn't imported it too, if not, import it.

Comment: I have imported it with Maven. I can import the class inside the source code - Idea gives no error.

Comment: Can you put a Java code snippet in your question in the lines where you're importing the HttpServlet API?

Comment: Yes, buddy, but you gotta import it anyway. something like " import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;". Please tell me if it worked.

I widely recommend you not to use Maven if you're new to Java programming. Just start with simple things, you'll understand it later.

Comment: I already solved it. And I'm not new to Java. Nor do I think novice Java programmers should avoid Maven, it is a great help when managing dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it. I went to File - Project Structure:

[image]

Then to Modules:

[image]

There was a Provided scope near the servlet module. I changed it to Compile:

[image]

And it worked!